# Netless appId for agora project

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I want the Netless appId for web agora. I searched it on google. but nothing found.
My Server is showing this

```
Error: find invalid appIdentifier: "netless appId"
```

How can I get this App id?

Answer (score 0):

Netless Appid can be found on the Agora console in the next coming weeks:  https://sso.agora.io/en/v4/signup